# Android App crashed without caused by

Tags: android, listview

I developed an android app with firebase and it works all fine. I decided to reused my code with a websocket instead of Firebase. With some help, I am developing it, and it is going pretty well. But I had a problem with one component.

Troubles comes when in one activity I try to open a dialog that contains a listview with android.r.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, in that moment the app crashed... with the error showed bellowed.

I debug the code that load info in the dialog and show without errors... I can't find the null object or the 'caused by' that usually it helps to find where can be the error...

```
06-12 00:59:56.718 2289-2289/wazodevs.com.coletask E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: wazodevs.com.coletask, PID: 2289
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
06-12 00:59:57.008 356-1014/? E/BandwidthController: No such appUid 10117 to remove
```

Thx 4 all!

Comment: in List which you are passing in ArrayAdapter any item is null, so that why its getting 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference. please check your list Items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was pretty fool.... The problem was that I had to create a list of strings to load arrayadapter, and the aImages has 8 elements, but the ObtainImgs filters and fill 3 of 8... but there wasn't null on the inspector... But when you try to go on... crashed..... Thx guys!

String[] listArray = new String[aImages.length];
listArray = obtainImgs(listArray);

Answer (score 0):

> I debug the code that load info in the dialog and show without
>   errors... I can't find the null object or the 'caused by' that usually
>   it helps to find where can be the error...

your dataset contains null values. Internally, ArrayAdapter does the following check:

```
final T item = getItem(position);
if (item instanceof CharSequence) {
    text.setText((CharSequence) item);
 } else {
    text.setText(item.toString());
 }
```

and that is the only place on `createViewFromResource` where `toString` is being called